# How to install colour profile screen device not listed

Tags: 11.10, colors, color-management

Under Natty I had a lovely .icc calibration file for my laptop's screen. It's awful without it.

Under Oneiric, when I go to 'Color' in the settings manager only my webcam is listed in the devices that can be colour managed. So I can't install my .icc profile.

I've installed all the gcm/argyl stuff but that hasn't got me anywhere either.

How can I (re)install my colour profile?

(I now consider this a bug. Report [filed on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-color-manager/+bug/881396), please mark it as affecting you if it does)

Comment: Work around: Running `dispwin my-calibration-file.icc` works to apply the icc file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until this bug is fixed, you can load your colour profile manually with

```
dispwin your_colour_profile.icc
```

(so you can put that in a script in your your autostart folder)

Comment: Thanks, my display color profile disappeared after upgrading to 15.10 from 15.04, and this command still works.  Still haven't discovered how to create a new device in Settings -> Color.  The official directions are very vague -- https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/color-virtualdevice.html

Answer (score 2):

I am having a similar issue in Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 (Gnome 3.18).
NOTE: I already had an .icc file for my display.

I was able to manually apply it to my unlisted display with the following command:

```
# dispwin -d 2 ./Dell_3007WFP-5000.icm
```

-d 2 specified the 2nd display (1st was my laptop built-in display)

Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Settings > Color

Select your monitor

click add profile

use the drop down list to select other

navigate to a compatible .icc profile and then click import

then click add

Comment: I think he said he cannot select his monitor because it doesn't show up there. :)

Comment: my apologies for not reading that completely. I do not know how to add devices.

Comment: I've been looking at the issue too, and it seems like gnome colour manager is no longer allowing nvidia driven displays to be corrected.

Comment: I'm using ATI/AMD...